# Get DE-9IM matrix in spatialite?

Tags: spatialite, sqlite, de-9im

Is there a way to get the DE-9IM matrix between two geometries in a Spatialite function, analogous to the st_relate() function in PostGIS?

(I find it very helpful to spatially join using intersect() and then do a count(*) group by with the DE-9IM matrix to determine what my interesections are like, whether on the edge or not.  Then I often calculate the ratio of areas for geometries that don't line up exactly to tell me about slivers.)

For reference:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM

http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Relate.html

Answer (score 1):

It seems you miss the `ST_relate` function like in PostGIS. Search "relate" word in [the reference functions](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-4.2.0.html) for version 4.2. The signature will look like below :

`ST_Relate( geom1 Geometry , geom2 Geometry , patternMatrix String ) : Integer`

patternMatrix is the DE-9IM pattern.

PS: If your spatialite version is old, `ST_relate` may be named `relate`

Comment: I understood that the wish is to get the complete matrix as an answer. Spatialite returns only true/false for a given matrix.

Comment: @user30184, you are correct.  I know about the three argument version of relate, I am hoping for a two argument version.

Comment: You should ask on the spatialite mailing list https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/spatialite-users to get further info for this two arg version availability and learn if there is a schedule for the function.